# Node-fetch problems with POST requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-fetch

In postman, I can successfully make this request:

[image]

And get this response:

[image]

Now I want to do the same request in my server.js file in node.js:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const SEN_URL =  "http://www.sentiment140.com/api/bulkClassifyJson" // URL of sentiment analysis
app.get('/api/sentimenttest', async (req, res) => {
  try{
    var sentiments = await fetch(SEN_URL, {method: "POST", body: {"data": [{"text": "I love you"}, {"text": "I hate you"}]}})
    console.log(sentiments)
    res.send(sentiments)
  }catch(error){
    console.log(error)
  }
})
```

This doesn't work. Here's what shows up in the browser when I go to localhost:5000/api/sentimenttest:

```
{"size":0,"timeout":0}
```

and here's the console output:

```
 Response {
   size: 0,
   timeout: 0,
   [Symbol(Body internals)]: 
    { body: 
       PassThrough {
         _readableState: [ReadableState],
         readable: true,
         _events: [Object],
         _eventsCount: 2,
         _maxListeners: undefined,
         _writableState: [WritableState],
         writable: false,
         allowHalfOpen: true,
         _transformState: [Object] },
      disturbed: false,
      error: null },
   [Symbol(Response internals)]: 
    { url: 'http://www.sentiment140.com/api/bulkClassifyJson',
      status: 200,
      statusText: 'OK',
      headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object] } } }
```

Since the request works just fine in postman, I think that the problem is with node-fetch, or the way that I use it, specifically how the `body` parameter is provided in the `fetch()` call. It seems like the API call does not contain what I want it to, since in the browser it says `"size":0`.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: [node-fetch usage examples](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) quite clearly show that you have to at least `JSON.stringify()` the body data or pass it in various other ways.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to await for json.

```
var sentiments = await fetch(SEN_URL, {method: "POST", body: {"data": [{"text": "I love you"}, {"text": "I hate you"}]}})
//Here 
await sentiments.json()
```

Also you can make request with `JSON.stringify()` for body. And it will be easier to manage your js object. Like this:

```
var data = {data: [{text: "I love you"}, {text: "I hate you"}]};
var body = JSON.stringify(data);
var sentiments = await fetch(SEN_URL, { method: "POST", body: body });
```

Comment: He _can_ and **must** use `JSON.stringify`, since it is required by the [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) module for sending JSON in POST requests.

Comment: Second await, the main point and first argument of your answer, is that really necessary?  This was about JSON.stringify() only.

Comment: @marekful, actually, it was also necessary, removing it results in an empty JSON object being returned by the server.

Comment: awesome solved the problem :)
const resp = await fetch(factor2API_Endpoint.SEND_OTP_SMS(to));
    console.log(await resp.json());
    return await resp.json();

Answer (score 1):

Since it can be easily overlooked within the accepted best answer, just wanted to point out that it's especially crucial to return the response as `response.json()`. The await part can all be in place correctly and still result in OP's `Response { size: 0, timeout: 0 etc }` if the .json() method is left off. This whole thread is about POST requests but the same applies to GET etc too.