Stripe: subscription creatiion gives no error, but nothing appears on dashboard
trying to create a subscription for a product on Stripe. The product already has a defined price. I tried with both directly the Price object and creating a new price object, the behavior remains the same.
a fetch request with the following code and JSON body object:
 async createSubscription(data) {
      try {
        const params = new URLSearchParams();
        params.append('customer', data.customer);
        params.append('cancel_at_period_end', data.cancel_at_period_end.toString());
        params.append('currency', data.currency);
        params.append('description', data.description);
        params.append('items[0][price_data][currency]',  data.items[0].price_data.currency);
        params.append('items[0][price_data][product]',   data.items[0].price_data.product);
        params.append('items[0][price_data][recurring]', data.items[0].price_data.recurring.interval);
        params.append('items[0][price_data][unit_amount]', data.items[0].price_data.unit_amount);


        const response = await fetch(url, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
              'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY}`,
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          },
        
        body: params});
       
        return {data: response};
      } catch (err) {
        return {error: err.message };
      }
    }

JSON:
{
    "customer": "cus_QjVBjHwGQiiHie",
    "cancel_at_period_end": false,
    "currency": "eur",
    "description": "my test subscription",

    "items": [
        {
            "price_data": {
                "currency": "eur",
                "product": "prod_Ql0OtnWNPRhvlh",
                
                "recurring": {
                    "interval": "month"
                },
                "unit_amount": 1000
            }
        }
    ]
}

API Response:
{
    "data": {
        "error": {
            "message": "Invalid object",
            "param": "items[0][price_data][recurring]",
            "request_log_url": "https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_VuvYP2QECpJRyD?t=1725541424",
            "type": "invalid_request_error"
        }
    }
}


The issue is {"size","timeout} is not what the Stripe API returned.
You need to also invoke .json() to see the response(which might be an error that tells you what's happening). See this related answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49842045/9769731
Also consider looking at your Stripe API logs for hints and help: https://docs.stripe.com/development/dashboard/request-logs
I'd also recommend not writing the code this way, you should use the official Stripe Node library. https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node

"message": "Invalid object",
"param": "items[0][price_data][recurring]

ok now that i checked, the error is that recurring must be an object that then contains the interval. i edited the post with the new details

sounds like you found the problem then and have a clear path to fixing it?

yeah basically it has to be in the object syntax that then contained a key. So it was like this:
"recurring": {
"interval": "month"
}
